# Oracle Regex Replace negative lookahead

Tags: regex, oracle

I'm writing some regex + queries to match US phone numbers. The one below with negative lookahead gets validated from a regex perspective, but doesn't work in Oracle due to negative lookahead not being supported. Can anyone please help me modify the query to work in Oracle?

```
select 'match' from dual WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('16665555555', '^1?(?!911)[2-9][0-9]{9}$');
```

It doesn't return a match for any number in oracle.

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(phone, '^1?[2-9]\d{9}$') and not REGEXP_LIKE(phone, '^1?911')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the accepted answer is the best and clearest way to do this. But just for reference, another option for a case like this would be to combine the restrictions you want on the first three characters (after the optional "1") and use alternation to cover all possible allowed cases.

In this case we can cover all possible allowed cases for the first three characters (after the optional "1") with three possibilities:

1. The characters match "[2-9][0-9]{2}" **and** the first character **is not** a 9. This case can be written as: "[2-8][0-9]{2}"
2. The characters match "[2-9][0-9]{2}" **and** the first character **is** 9, but the second character **is not** 1. This case can be written as: "9[02-9][0-9]"
3. The characters match "[2-9][0-9]{2}" **and** the first character **is** 9 **and** the second character **is** 1, but the third character **is not** 1. This case can be written as: "91[02-9]"

Putting this all together we get:

```
select 'match' from dual WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('9115555555', '^1?([2-8][0-9]{2}|9[02-9][0-9]|91[02-9])[2-9][0-9]{6}$');
```